# при съемке фото отображается в неверной ориентации

Tags: android, камера

Есть следующий код,для обработки фото, однако все мои попытки сделать верную ориентацию тщетны. подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?

```
 public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
        return;

    mCamera.stopPreview();

    setCameraDisplayOrientation();

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void setCameraDisplayOrientation() {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", "setCameraDisplayOrientation - camera null");
        return;
    }

    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(0, info);

    WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int rotation = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    int degrees = 0;

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    int rotate = (degrees + 270) % 360;
    parameters.setRotation(rotate);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

}

попробовал использовать exif, но результат стал еще хуже

```
public void rotateBitmap(File tempFile) {
        if (tempFile != null) {
            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempFile.getAbsolutePath(), opts);
            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            Log.d("TAG", "Exif: " + orientation);
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(0));
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    matrix.postRotate(0);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                    Log.d("TAG", "Exif: " + orientation);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            Bitmap destBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                destBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

orientation всегда=8, а изображение выходит верх ногами...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157984/android-camera-surfaceview-orientation